# Find last occurrence of string in document not in line using regular expression

Tags: html, regex, xml, html-table

I tried this **/session=s(.+?)">/g** for searching a string in this xml document:

```
<html><body><p><table border="1">
        <tr>
        <td><a href="viewSessionLog.jsp?session=s0001">s0001</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><a href="viewSessionLog.jsp?session=s0002">s0002</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><a href="viewSessionLog.jsp?session=s0003">s0003</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><a href="viewSessionLog.jsp?session=s0004">s0004</a></td>
        </tr>
                    </table>
                </p>
            </body>
        </html>
```

And I got :

```
`0001`
`0002`
`0003`
`0004`
```

But I want only '0004'.

How can I do using regular expression only?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var lastMatch = '',
        str = document.documentElement.innerHTML,
        regex = /session=s(.+?)">/g,
        captured;

    while (captured = regex.exec(str))
        lastMatch = captured[1];
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f4n319d3/

If for some reason you don't want to loop the `exec` function, I think the only other option is to do use a `replace` function and assign `lastMatch` inside it so that you will be left with the last match:

```
    var lastMatch = '',
        str = document.documentElement.innerHTML,
        regex = /session=s(.+?)">/g;

    str.replace(regex, function(str, match) {
        lastMatch = match;
    });
```

In both cases `lastMatch` will give you the last matched capture group.

Answer (score 0):

```html
var sContent = span.span1 > .span2
var last_dot_class_name_regex = new RegExp("\.([^.]+)$");
last_dot_class_name_text = last_dot_class_name_regex.execsContent);

out put
last_dot_class_name_text[1] = span2
last_dot_class_name_text[2] = .span2
```